# redirect loop in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

My users sign up at the root url by providing an `email`, an `account_type`, and a `password`. They get an email asking for confirmation. Once they confirm their email, they are able to sign in. But before they can use any of the site features, I want for them to complete their profile by providing a `username` and setting up a Stripe account. My initial idea was to do this as a `before_action` in the `ApplicationController`. So like:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
 before_action :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account

 private
 def current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account
  if user_signed_in? && current_user.username.blank?
    redirect_to users_onboard_path
  end
 end  
end
```

However, this causes a redirect loop when I sign in with a newly approved user. Terminal output is:

```
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/users/onboard
Filter chain halted as :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account rendered or redirected
```

Why is it going to that page and THEN redirecting to the page again?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach seems to be correct. However, using the current approach would lead to a redirect loop, if the original request is directed towards `users_onboard_path`.
 
In order to avoid a loop, you would need to skip the `current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account` before_action call when the original request is directed to the `users/onboard` action. In order to do this, you could add the following line to `users_controller.rb`, right at the top, inside the controller class(Assuming that file contains the `onboard` action):

```
skip_before_action :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account, only: [:onboard]
```

By doing this, we would basically skip `current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account` action being called before the execution of `onboard` action, and hence, remove the loop.

UPDATE:

I'll try to illustrate this with the help of a test app that I've created:
The `application_controller.rb` file of the app is as follows:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account

  private

  def current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account
    p "I'm in the before_action call current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account"
    if some_condition?
      p "I'm redirecting to the onboard API"
      redirect_to onboard_users_path
    end
  end

  def some_condition?
    true
  end
end
```

In this file, we define a `before_action` callback to redirect to the onboarding path.
The `users_controller.rb` file of this app is as follows:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  def login
    p "I'm in login"
    render json: { message: "This is a message from login action" }
  end

  def onboard
    p "I'm in onboard!"
    render json: { message: "This is a message from onboard action" }
  end
end
```

When I try to hit the login API, I run into a redirect loop as seen in the terminal output:

```
Started GET "/users/login" for ::1 at 2019-04-10 11:16:09 +0530
Processing by UsersController#login as */*
"I'm in the before_action call current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account"
"I'm redirecting to the onboard API"
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/users/onboard
Filter chain halted as :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/onboard" for ::1 at 2019-04-10 11:16:09 +0530
Processing by UsersController#onboard as */*
"I'm in the before_action call current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account"
"I'm redirecting to the onboard API"
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/users/onboard
Filter chain halted as :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

Basically, we hit the `before_action` method in the call to login first, and try to redirect to `onboard_users_path`. However, when calling `/users/onboard` in the redirect, we hit the `before_action` block again, and that again tries to redirect us to `/users/onboard` and this becomes a loop.
However, if we add a `skip_before_action :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account, only: [:onboard]` to our `users_controller.rb`, we get the following output:

```
Started GET "/users/login" for ::1 at 2019-04-10 11:22:34 +0530
Processing by UsersController#login as */*
"I'm in the before_action call current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account"
"I'm redirecting to the onboard API"
Redirected to http://localhost:3001/users/onboard
Filter chain halted as :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account rendered or redirected
Completed 302 Found in 3ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)


Started GET "/users/onboard" for ::1 at 2019-04-10 11:22:34 +0530
Processing by UsersController#onboard as */*
"I'm in onboard!"
Completed 200 OK in 1ms (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.0ms)
```

As seen in the log, the login call redirects to onboard, but here, the `before_action` redirection is skipped, and we get the response as desired.
Similarly, in your example also, the first call redirects to `onboard`, and then subsequent calls also keep getting redirected because the `before_action` callback runs for `onboard` action as well!

Comment: thanks for the help! the original after sign in request is directed to the `root_path`. my before_action (`current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account`) directs any new user to the onboard path. i don't see any loop there.

Comment: Hi! I've updated the answer with an example to illustrate what is happening. For that purpose, I've used a sample test_app to simulate your project(with similar method names). 
Basically, the before_action gets triggered on all URLs. So, once the condition is met, and the `before_action` is triggered, it gets triggered again when the redirection to `onboard` happens.
I hope the update in the answer should make things more clear.

Answer (score 1):

The approach is completely valid.
You'll just have to check the current controller and action: if they're already on `users_onboard_path`, you don't need to redirect again.

Comment: yeah i though that my approach would be valid as well, but for some reason i'm stuck. logging in as a user without a username just sends me down a redirect loop, and i can't figure out why.

Answer (score 1):

Your App redirects because when you hit the onboarding, the condition `users_signed_in? && current_user.username.blank?` is still true. Therefore the same callback is fired because all your controllers inherit from `ApplicationController` and you end up with a redirect loop.

You could add a check in your callback to verify you are not already in the onboarding

```
return if request.path =~ /onboard/
```

Another solution would be to have all your controller actions relative to the onboarding to skip the callback

```
skip_before_action :current_user_has_complete_profile_and_stripe_account, only: [:onboard]
```